# Can a transaction be posted to the blockchain without an associated account?

Tags: transactions

Can I post a transaction to the EOS blockchain that is signed using keys that aren't associated with an existing account?  How does the blockchain detect these transactions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the current documentation on GitHub, no.

> Accounts
>
> An account is a human-readable name that is stored on the blockchain. It can be owned by an individual or group of individuals depending on permissions configuration. **An account is required to transfer or otherwise push a transaction to the blockchain.**

[documentation](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Accounts-&-Permissions#accounts)

Answer (score 5):

No.

You can send it but it will be rejected by nodeos due to invalid signature.

Comment: Did you try to do that already and got an error? because I think the question makes sense since we can have keys associated with permissions, not accounts. (maybe my state is false and I misunderstood something)

Comment: According to Dan Larimer on Telegram, the Block Producers validate that the signing keys belong to a valid account and reject the transaction if they cannot find a matching account.  I believe it is related to enforcing permissions and the like in the BP code.